# What is the TFileStream equivalent to pascal IO Append(F)?

Tags: delphi

I assume it is:

```
FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite);
FS.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
```

Is that correct? is the open mode correct or maybe `fmOpenWrite` or need to add `fmShareDenyNone`?

PS: For `Rewrite(F)` I used `FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);`

---

Based on @David's comments I ended up using `THandleStream`

```
procedure LOG(const FileName: string; S: string);
const
  FILE_APPEND_DATA = 4;
  OPEN_ALWAYS = 4;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  Stream: THandleStream;
begin
  Handle := CreateFile(PChar(FileName),
    FILE_APPEND_DATA, // Append data to the end of file
    0, nil,
    OPEN_ALWAYS, // If the specified file exists, the function succeeds and the last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
                 // If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set to zero.
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

  if Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  try
    Stream := THandleStream.Create(Handle);
    try
      S := S + #13#10;
      Stream.WriteBuffer(S[1], Length(S) * SizeOf(Char));
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FileClose(Handle);
  end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: You don't want to read, so why use read/write? If you want to get cute you can use `THandleStream` passing a handle from `CreateFile` and the `FILE_APPEND_DATA` flag to ensure you always append.

Comment: And calling `CreateFile` yourself allows you to use the `OPEN_ALWAYS` creation disposition and so avoid having race conditions over whether the file exists or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it would be

```
FStream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenWrite);
FStream.Seek(0, soEnd);
```

You can see an example in `TBinaryWriter.Create` or `TStreamWriter.Create` - or you just opt to use one of these classes directly.

Comment: Undeclared identifier: 'soEnd'

Comment: it's soFromEnd :) - http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_soFromEnd.html

Comment: Depends on the Delphi version. In Berlin we have `TSeekOrigin = (soBeginning, soCurrent, soEnd);` As you didn't specify any version I usually assume the current one.

Comment: @MartynA,  I'm on Delphi 5 where there is no `TSeekOrigin`. `soFromEnd` is declared as `soFromEnd = 2`. even the docs are misleading. look at RBA link. it says: "`soFromEnd` is one of the TSeekOrigin values..." and the docs [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TSeekOrigin.html) show `TSeekOrigin = (soBeginning, soCurrent, soEnd);`. I assumed Uwe made a typo, please spare me your lecture.

Comment: @RBA, actually the docs are wrong. `soFromEnd` is not part of `TSeekOrigin`

Comment: @UweRaabe, Thanks I've looked into `TStreamWriter.Create` as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like this

```
var
  FileName: string;
  FS: TFileStream;
  sOut: string;
  i: Integer;
  Flags: Word;
begin
  FileName := ...; // get your file name from somewhere
  Flags := fmOpenReadWrite;
  if not FileExists(FileName) then
    Flags := Flags or fmCreate;
  FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName, Flags);
  try
    FS.Position := FS.Size;  // Will be 0 if file created, end of text if not
    sOut := 'This is test line %d'#13#10;
    for i := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      sOut := Format(sOut, [i]);
      FS.Write(sOut[1], Length(sOut) * SizeOf(Char)); 
    end;

  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This code also verify if the file doesn't exist, and if not then creates the file.

Concerning the flags, you can find a definition for each one of them in the [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_FileOpen.html)

Comment: This is a big weakness of `TFileStream`. No access to `OPEN_ALWAYS` creation disposition. My code that does this calls `CreateFile` and then uses `THandleStream`. Beyond convenience this also avoids a race condition.